# Creating a product programmatically without deprecated functions

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, programmatically

I have the following code which creates a product programmatically but it uses deprecated functions eg the save

Therefore my question is how do you create a product programmatically without using deprecated functions?

```
public function __construct (
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
)
{
  $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}

public function createProduct(){
  $simpleProduct1 = $this->productFactory->create();
  $simpleProduct1->setData('sku', 'Test Simple Product 1');
  $simpleProduct1->setData('name', 'Test Simple Product 1');
  $simpleProduct1->setData('website_ids', array(1)); // product can be found in main website
  $simpleProduct1->setData('attribute_set_id', 4);
  $simpleProduct1->setData('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
  $simpleProduct1->setData('visibility', 4);
  $simpleProduct1->setData('price', 12);
  $simpleProduct1->setData('type_id', 'simple');
  $simpleProduct1->setData('stock_data', array(  // set product quantity
   'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
   'manage_stock' => 1,
   'is_in_stock' => 1,
   'qty' => 100
  ));
  $simpleProduct1->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function __construct (
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
)
{
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function createProduct(){
    $simpleProduct1 = $this->productFactory->create();
    $simpleProduct1->setData('sku', 'Test Simple Product 1');
    $simpleProduct1->setData('name', 'Test Simple Product 1');
    $simpleProduct1->setData('website_ids', array(1)); // product can be found in main website
    $simpleProduct1->setData('attribute_set_id', 4);
    $simpleProduct1->setData('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $simpleProduct1->setData('visibility', 4);
    $simpleProduct1->setData('price', 12);
    $simpleProduct1->setData('type_id', 'simple');
    $simpleProduct1->setData('stock_data', array(  // set product quantity
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
        'manage_stock' => 1,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 100
    ));
    $this->productRepository->save($simpleProduct1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I say something like this

```
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productInterfaceFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->productInterfaceFactory = $productInterfaceFactory;
        $this->productRepositoryInterface = $productRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * Create random product.
     *
     * @param int $websiteId
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor
     */
    public function createProduct($websiteId = 1, $typeId = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
    {

        $quantity = rand(1, 20);
        $product = $this->productInterfaceFactory
            ->create()
            ->setSku('whatever')
            ->setTypeId($typeId)
            ->setWebsiteIds([$websiteId])
            ->setStockData([
                'is_in_stock' => $quantity > 0 ? 1 : 0,
                'qty'         => $quantity,
            ]);

        try {
            $product = $this->productRepositoryInterface->save($product);
            return $product;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
    }
```